# sending an SQL query using an API call via PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl, post

In a php file I am making a POST call via an API to a database. At the moment it is not returning anything useful. (The file is at the bottom). I have various debugging within the php file.

The result I get is:

```
200
Error parsing XML
```

I understand 200 is a successful connection.
But obviously there is a error parsing the XML
If I am echoing the $response and there is nothing output (as it should between 200 and Error parsing XML) then I guess there is an issue with the $URL. Anything obvious someone can see or is there other debugging I can do?

I cut `$url .= '&SQLquery=' . urlencode($query);` and moved it to the top and removed the SQLQuery from the original $URL variable but that just produced more errors. I did this because it looked like a duplicate.

The documentation for the API has the following
`http://localhost:82/sqlquery?apikey=ABC123&format=json&configuration=0`

{ *I have replaced the actual API keys with ABC123 }

```
<?php

// API endpoint URL
$url = 'http://orcus.companyname.local:82/SQLquery';

// API parameters
$query = "Select RESOURCENAME from RESOURCEMASTER where RESOURCESTATUS='Active'";
$apiKey = 'ABC123';
$format = 'xml';
$configuration = 0;

// Build the API URL with query parameters
$url .= '?apikey=' . urlencode($apiKey);
$url .= '&format=' . urlencode($format);
$url .= '&configuration=' . urlencode($configuration);
$url .= '&SQLquery=' . urlencode($query);

// Create a new cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set the cURL options
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Enable verbose mode for cURL 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

// Make the GET request and get the response
$response = curl_exec($curl);

// Get the HTTP response code
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

// Check if the request was successful
if ($httpCode >= 200 && $httpCode < 300) {
    // Process the response
    // ...
    echo $httpCode. "<br>";
} else {
    echo "HTTP Error: " . $httpCode;
}

// Show structure of XML
echo $response;

// Check if an error occurred
if ($response === false) {
    $error = curl_error($curl);
    echo "cURL Error: " . $error;
} else {
    // Process the response
    // Assuming the response is in XML format
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
    
    //Inspect structure of XML
    //var_dump($xml); // or print_r($xml);
    

    // Check parsing
    if ($xml === false) {
        echo "Error parsing XML\n";
        exit;
    }

    // Debugging
    if(!$xml){
        echo 'Fail to load XML file Simon.';
    }

    // Handle the XML data as per your requirement
    // Example: Extracting the resource names
    $resourceNames = $xml->xpath('//RESOURCENAME');


    // Output the resource names
    foreach ($resourceNames as $name) {
        echo $name . "<br>";
    }
}

// Close the cURL resource
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Can you try `var_dump($response);` to see exactly what the nature of the output (if any) is? Paste the output in your question (or a sample, if it's too big). Sometimes `echo` doesn't show absolutely every detail.

Comment: I suppose you should check the logging of the api itself for errors.

Comment: _"The documentation for the API has the following"_ - there is no parameter named  `SQLquery` in that example URL. Are you supposed to send it as a GET parameter? Or are you perhaps supposed to send the actual SQL as the URL _path_, where it actually says `sqlquery` in that URL you have given? (Would be rather weird, and probably quite error-prone - but we don't know anything else about your API so far.)

Comment: @ADyson Add var_dump($response) gave me:
<value>Command: &SQLquery=Select+RESOURCENAME+from+RESOURCEMASTER+where+RESOURCESTATUS='Active' is not recognized</value>
Replacing the spaced with %20 didn't help.

Comment: @CBroe You are correct, the documentation isn't great. I have interrupted the sqlquery as both the query itself in the URL (didn't work) and a variable (via php). Some API calls can be made via the address bar as GET is the default. But passing an SQL statement requires a POST which means I can't do it via a web browsers URL. So I suspect I need to do it from a php (or jscript). At least that is how I have understood it.

Comment: _"But passing an SQL statement requires a POST"_ - okay, then you need to start making one ... Right now you are appending all your parameters to the URL, so they will be GET parameters, even if you chose POST as request method. You need to supply them via CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS option.